# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS ASP.NET c# over 100 redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, error-handling

i am creating a ashx file that:

- Gets data from external url
- Writes the data into a database
- Looks if the http header contains a new link for new results
- redirects to that url
- and does it all over again

But the request redirects itself for over a 100 times, **wich also is needed**.

But Chrome i get after around 20 redirects the error:

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I know it is a good security thing, but i need it canceled in my application.

Is there a fix for this problem?

The other functions work fine, only the error 310 is called after 20 redirects, and i need to redirect it like 100 times.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> But the request redirects itself for over a 100 times, **wich also is needed**.

No, what is needed is that it gets to all the URLs. The fact that it does it in http-header redirect is an implementation detail, and is a *bad design*, for the reason that it won't work: browsers don't like that - it looks very much like an error to them.

So: you need to find a new design - maybe:

- doing everything without ever using a browser (just make the requests server side, or do the processing *without using http requests in the first place*)
- using a few http-header redirects, then client-side redirect via script
- using a few http-header redirects, then client-side redirect via meta-refresh

Comment: With every redirect, i get a new url, to load the next url, so i need to run it over a 100 times. I am trying to load the ashx file using a vbscript, so without a browser, but after 20 times the script stops loading. How would i get the data without a request but from an url?

Comment: @DavidRaijmakers again, you need to find a better design; this **WILL NOT WORK**; this is a browser sanity-check device that you have no control over.

Comment: @DavidRaijmakers to make a request without a browser you can use any number of tools `WebClient`, `HttpClient`, etc - or even just `curl`